# Backbone is not defined even its loaded with RequreJS

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm setting up a app with Require JS and backbone. But in my setup backbone is not loading correctly even if I included all the things

This is my main file.

```
require.config({

paths: {
    /*app: 'app',*/

    /*Libs and other resources*/
    jquery: 'libs/jquery',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone'
},

shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    }
}
});


require(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
   console.log(Backbone);
});
```

This is the status of the scripts.
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Removed the shim according to comments. But still its not working.

[image]

Comment: Could you please try to expand the `Uncaught Error: Script error for: ../..` and see where is it originated from ? And also [requirejs docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) say that, `Remember: only use shim config for non-AMD scripts, scripts that do not already call define(). The shim config will not work correctly if used on AMD scripts`. Please make sure that you haven't used non amd modules.

Comment: @Cyclone's comment is probably the answer, Backbone has been AMD compliant since 1.1.1 http://backbonejs.org/#changelog

Comment: @Cyclone and nikoshr Removed the shim and still no luck.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console ?

Comment: Yes, You can see on the bottom of the image

Comment: I'm not sure from where is it trying to load the '...js'. In the console '$' and '_' are available and Backbone is not

Comment: Are you sure the path to backbone is correct?

Comment: @Michael.Lumley yes. check http://i.imgur.com/P3DPIi6.png

Comment: Are you loading the latest version of Backbone?

Comment: Thanks for the all who replied. I found my problem that is my backbone file is corrupted when I copy in the windows explorer. Once I re download it  starts to work. Cheers

Comment: You should answer your question and describe what made you think the file might be corrupted and how to check that. Typically this error is cause by missing "shim" for non-AMD modules, wrong paths, network errors while loading or ... even a script with a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

This happen due to a corrupted backbone.js lib files. I copied this file via a phpstorm from some other place in the project.

I have tried multiple suggestions and non of them are worked. At last I just created a single html file and tried to backbone worked there. Then I realized there may be a problem with backbone.js and **just re-downloaded it and replaced**. Now everything got to work.